# Nginx Multiple Locations

Tags: nginx

I have already 5 hours here figuring on how to solve but i can't.

Assuming that we have the following dir structure

```
/var/www/key1
/var/www/key1/wwwdir
/var/www/key1/dir1
/var/www/key1/dir2
```

And another one

```
/var/www/key2
/var/www/key2/wwwdir
/var/www/key2/dir1
/var/www/key2/dir2
```

I want when i type for example **http://mysite.com/key1** to get files from `/var/www/key1/wwwdir` and when i type **http://mysite.com/key2** to get files from `/var/www/key2/wwwdir`

I have the following nginx config for all of my `"keys"`

```
server {
    listen       80;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

And key1.conf is

```
location ~/key2 {

    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    alias /var/www/key2/wwwdir;

    location ~* \.php$ {


        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-fpm/key2.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work. When i'm requesting the following url **http://mysite.com/key2** i get **BAD Gateway error.**

In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` there is an error that
`/var/www/key2/wwwdir/key2/index.php that file does not exists` (the key2 exists 2 times which i'm not sure why)

When i type

`http://mysite.com/key2` i want to get files from `/var/www/key2/wwwdir` .

Examples:

```
http://mysite.com/key2 => /var/www/key2/wwwdir
http://mysite.com/key2/admin => /var/www/key2/wwwdir/admin
```

*Of course i want the same with my another vhost key1*

Answer (score 3):

You should use `alias` instead of `root`.

Explanation: if you use `root` the uri after `location` will append to `rootdir`. This is the reason why appears `key2` twice. But if you use `alias` the uri after `location` will not append.

For example:

```
location /test {
  root /wwwdir/mydir;
}
```

The `example.com/test/index.html` serves `/wwdir/mydir/test/index.html`.

```
location /test {
  alias /wwwdir/mydir;
}
```

The `example.com/test/index.html` serves `/www/mydir/index.html` (`test` part does not appear).

See more [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

Comment: Hello Sir. StIl doesn't work for me. I edited my first post and added my entire config. Please see it again.

Comment: And also in error.log now i'm getting  ( "/etc/nginx/html404" failed (2: No such file or directory) )

Comment: Please use `location /key2` not `location ~/key2` (notice the `~`)!